# PHP in_array function not working in server

Tags: php

I use this function and Its Fine on Local means when `$hexIpStr` exist function return `false` otherwise return `true`,
But when I Deploy my Project on Server this Function only Return True,
$arr is 2D array.

```
function ipChecker($arr, $hexIp)
{
    $hexIpStr = "HEX=" . $hexIp;
    foreach ($arr as $members) {
        if (in_array($hexIpStr, $members)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The function is for example called with these values:

```
$hexIp = 'f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6';
$arr = array(
  0 => [
    0 => 'FullName=mehdi',
    1 => 'Email=test@gmail.com',
    2 => 'IP=127.0.0.1',
    3 => 'HEX=f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6',
    4 => '=>',
    5 => 'Opinion=1 ',
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => '',
  ],
);
```

no its not answer because its fine in the server i get this

> FullName=asd Email=kingblack5230@gmail.com IP=192.119.160.197
>   HEX=dd029394f038b0775138a23df8d9cddd => Opinion=1 and its right and i
>   use this function to get user ip:

```
function GetRealIp()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 }
    return $ip;}
```

Comment: What did it return on local ? If it returns true, it only means that the variable `$hexIpStr` holding the data is not found in the array `$members`.

Comment: no,the only different is local and server

Comment: Can you `var_dump($hexIpStr);` and `var_dump(members);` to check if `$hexIpStr` is actually found in the array `members`.

Comment: i     var_dump($hexIpStr) , and its founded
C:\xampp\htdocs\php2.exp\HomeWorks\poll\functions.php:20:string 'HEX=f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6' (length=36)
    then return false,but in server only return true at all

Comment: Did you do the `var_dump()` on the server ? (should not be done on the local as it is working fine there). With the code above, the only reason it is returning true it because the `$hexIpStr` is not present in `$members`.

Comment: yes i did var_dump in server and its always return true, im sure $hexIpStr exist even on the server,casue i save that on a file same like local

Comment: put your `$arr` output here.

Comment: The code produce unexpected results because it checks only the first item of `$arr` and returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function "returns early" (and thus breaks the `foreach`) after checking the first child for your *HEX=...* string. This means you only ever check the first member.

Given this `$arr`, your member is in there, just not at the first position:

```
array(
  0 => [
    0 => 'FullName=blub',
    1 => 'Email=blub@gmail.com',
    2 => 'IP=1.2.3.4',
    3 => 'HEX=6465ec74397c9126916786bbcd6d7601',
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => 'FullName=mehdi',
    1 => 'Email=test@gmail.com',
    2 => 'IP=127.0.0.1',
    3 => 'HEX=f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6',
  ],
)
```

It would return `true`, because only `in_array('HEX=f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6', ['HEX=6465ec74397c9126916786bbcd6d7601'])` is checked.

You should restructure your function so it can only "`return` early" if it found your member, and if not, continues to check all members, and returns the other case only in the end:

```
function ipChecker($arr, $hexIp)
{
    $hexIpStr = "HEX=" . $hexIp;
    foreach ($arr as $members) {
        if (in_array($hexIpStr, $members)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6`*([#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134324/php-in-array-function-not-working-in-server#comment91218890_52134324))* is `md5('127.0.0.1')`, this is likely not the value (IP) you expect / that is in `$members`. You likely expect a public IP.

If you rely on `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` this can be the issue. If your server is proxying the request to your PHP worker on the same machine (rather than using e.g. `mod_php` directly), `REMOTE_ADDR` will be the IP of the proxy (`127.0.0.1`/`localhost`) rather than the visitor.

In this case, you should dump `$_SERVER` and check for a variable `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` / use that instead of `REMOTE_ADDR`, the proxy server will likely add this to include the original IP.

Comment: No its not the answer explain why in the question

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Yeah, it was a guess. After seeing your `$arr`, I found a more likely issue with the loop. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52134997/7362396